# How to tell if a subview was tapped twice

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview, uitouch

I have a UIImageView that I allocated inside of a UIView. I want to double tap that subview using the TOUCHESENDED or TOUCHESBEGAN and send a callback or at least a log. I would appreciate anyone who can upload some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, it is not recommended to subclass `UIImageView`, but this is for drawing, if you only want to catch events, you may subclass `UIImageVIew`and catch the event. Then look at the `tapCount` property of the touch. As per http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITouch/tapCount

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't put that link not inline, it display correctly in JS preview, but not on the page.

Comment: I actualy ended up initializing it as another king of view, then making a file to control that then put the touchesBegan method inside that .m file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use the *.tapCount* property inside **touchesBegan:**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == yourThing) {
            NSLog(@"%i taps", numTaps);
    }
}
```

Comment: but what I am taping is a subview of my Super and I want to ask my subView how many times it's been tapped

Comment: This will print how many times a specific view has been touched.